# MongoDB: Regroup by two field with different value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I created a nodejs app in Typescript.
I want to group documents by two fields "one_id" and "two_id" with specified one_id value.

Here is my data in my collection:

```
{  
   "_id":"5a8b2953007a1922f00124fd",
   "one_id":"307973260186877954",
   "two_id":"415228402765660181"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8b29a3007a1922f00124fe",
   "one_id":"415228402765660181",
   "two_id":"307973260186877954"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8c119bf6ba49302c3ef67e",
   "one_id":"394199132195127306",
   "two_id":"270131587092316161"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8c11a4f6ba49302c3ef67f",
   "one_id":"270131587092316161",
   "two_id":"394199132195127306"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8c33132a182308a836bc1c",
   "one_id":"307973260186877954",
   "two_id":"397036401075552256"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8c33242a182308a836bc1d",
   "one_id":"397036401075552256",
   "two_id":"307973260186877954"
}
```

And if I want to get pairs with one_id="307973260186877954", the excepted result would be: (must have another document with "inversed" fields content)

```
{  
   "_id":"5a8b2953007a1922f00124fd",
   "one_id":"307973260186877954",
   "two_id":"415228402765660181"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8b29a3007a1922f00124fe",
   "one_id":"415228402765660181",
   "two_id":"307973260186877954"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8c33132a182308a836bc1c",
   "one_id":"307973260186877954",
   "two_id":"397036401075552256"
}
{  
   "_id":"5a8c33242a182308a836bc1d",
   "one_id":"397036401075552256",
   "two_id":"307973260186877954"
}
```

I don't know if you understand me.

Thank you, I hope someone will understand me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` to self join the rows and output the document when there is a match and `$project` with exclusion to drop the joined field.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":col,
    "localField":"one_id",
    "foreignField":"two_id",
    "as":"onetwo"
  }},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":col,
    "localField":"two_id",
    "foreignField":"one_id",
    "as":"twoone"
  }},
  {"$match":{"onetwo.0":{"$exists":true}, "twoone.0":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$project":{"onetwo":0,"twoone":0}}
])
```

Comment: I updated the question, look what I expect and what is my collection.

Comment: `{ _id: 5a8b2953007a1922f00124fd,
  one_id: '307973260186877954',
  two_id: '415228402765660181' }
{ _id: 5a8b29a3007a1922f00124fe,
  one_id: '415228402765660181',
  two_id: '307973260186877954' }
{ _id: 5a8c1068f6ba49302c3ef67d,
  one_id: '307973260186877954',
  two_id: '394199132195127306' }
{ _id: 5a8c33132a182308a836bc1c,
  one_id: '307973260186877954',
  two_id: '397036401075552256' }
{ _id: 5a8c33242a182308a836bc1d,
  one_id: '397036401075552256',
  two_id: '307973260186877954' }
`

Comment: Work but `{ _id: 5a8c1068f6ba49302c3ef67d,
  one_id: '307973260186877954',
  two_id: '394199132195127306' }` should not be displayed

Comment: I think I got it. Can you check the updated answer ?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I just added `{
            $match: {
                $or: [{
                    one_id: userM.id
                }, {
                    two_id: userM.id
                }]
            }
        },`  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yw. Did the answer not work for you ? Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be your solution. Not sure. Just gave it a try

```
db.TempCollections.aggregate([  
   {  
      $lookup:{  
         from:"TempCollections",
         let:{
            leftone_id:"$one_id",
            lefttwo_id:"$two_id"
        },
        pipeline:[
            {
                $match: {
                      $expr: {
                         $and: [
                            {
                               $eq: [
                                  "$one_id",
                                  "$$lefttwo_id"
                               ]
                            },
                            {
                               $eq: [
                                  "$two_id",
                                  "$$leftone_id"
                               ]
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   }
            }
        ],
         as:"Final"
      }
   }
],
{
allowDiskUse:true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I forgot to mention that I want to specify the one_id to match